# Adding post ID as a class to attachment images

Tags: wordpress, function, filter, attachment, attr

I have this code and it was working earlier but recently it stopped working, not sure why.

```
function addclassfeaturedimage($attr) {
  remove_filter('wp_get_attachment_image_attributes','addclassfeaturedimage');
  $attr['class'] .=  get_the_ID() ;
  return $attr;
}
add_filter('wp_get_attachment_image_attributes','addclassfeaturedimage');
```

When working it adds the post ID to the attachment image class.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Filter **wp_get_attachment_image_attributes** [used by function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_get_attachment_image_attributes/) wp_get_attachment_image()

Try to check **$attachment_id** parameter of **wp_get_attachment_image()**.

This might help.